# Mixin giving "could be instantiated with a different subtype of constraint" error

Tags: typescript, generics, mixins

In the following code Bar gives the error `Class 'Bar' incorrectly extends base class 'TBase'. 'Bar' is assignable to the constraint of type 'TBase', but 'TBase' could be instantiated with a different subtype of constraint 'Foo'.(2415)`, why?  There are similar questions but those seem to boil down to code that tries to use two different types for a generic, for example `func<T>(a:T):T` where func is returning a copy of a with extra properties.   But I don't understand how that's an issue here since as far as I can tell I'm not enforcing any constraint on Bar.

```
class Foo {}
type GConstructor<T> = new (...args: any[]) => T;

function Bar<TBase extends Foo>(Base: GConstructor<TBase>) {
  return class Bar extends Base {
    bar(){}
  };
}

function Bar2<TBase extends GConstructor<Foo>>(Base: TBase) {
  return class Bar2 extends Base {
    bar(){}
  };
}
```

Comment: This is essentially "working as intended" as per [ms/TS#52971](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/52971) supposedly to protect against something like `const Qux = Bar(class {bar = 1});` where the mixin might conflict with the extended class (`bar` is a method in the mixin but a number in the base). But there's no real explanation in there for why it should work for one but fail for the other.  Does that fully address the question? If not I suppose someone should try to get more feedback from the language maintainers on that issue or file a new one. If so I could write up an answer.